# Wrap first and second word in two different spans with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have tried two other suggestions found here to put a span around a word but each time it resulted in the span appearing above the text and not around it.

**I have the following code:**

```
<div class="dateCalendar">
June 10
</div>
```

**The jQuery I am currently using is:**

> $('.dateCalendar').html(function(i, v) { return v.replace(/\s(.*?)\s/,
>   ' $1 '); });

**The HTML output is showing this:**

```
<div class="dateCalendar">
<span></span>
June 10
</div>
```

Ideally in the end I would like to wrap the *month* in a span and the *date* in another span so I can style them differently in css.

Some notes that may be helpful to know:

- .dateCalendar will appear more than once on a page
- The date is coded in PHP within a Wordpress plugin that I can not alter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('.dateCalendar').html(function(i, v) { 
    return $.trim(v).replace(/(\w+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'); 
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8bjMD/)

Answer (score 1):

How about this - assuming only two words:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qAN82/)

```
$('.dateCalendar').each(function () {
  var cal = $(this); 
  var texts = $(this).text().split(" ");
  cal.empty();                   
  $.each(texts,function (i, text) {
    cal.append('<span class="' + (i == 0 ? "month" : "year") + '" >'+text+'</span>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The reason it's failing is because the resulting content isn't wrapped inside any tag.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZymGK/1/. Basically this returns an array of `span` elements for each "word" (delimited by spaces) and make that the content of each `div` element with the class `.dateCalendar`.